# Parsing html data in params for xml response using CDATA

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, xml, cdata

In the api, i'm generating a Xml response by hitting the url with request data in params. It contains some field which have html content and tags.The content is getting saved correctly in DB but when the response is getting generated the tags are being encoded which will happen as we need to skip those fields while parsing. I would like to know that how can i implement CDATA in order to skip the specific fields while parsing.

```
def generate_mobile_api_success_response(status_code, format, request_id, content = nil)
  format_type_method, options_hash, content_type = get_format_method(format)

  data = { "request_id" => request_id, "status" => status_code, "message" => status_message(status_code)}
  data["data"] = content unless content.blank?
  data = generate_data_format(format, data)

  resp = [status_code, { "Content-Type" => content_type , "request_id" => request_id}, data.send(format_type_method, options_hash)]
  generate_active_controller_response_format(resp)
  resp
end
```

Content passed is a params hash, and format is xml. resp contains the following data when i tried to print it.Detailed description tag contains the encoded data

```
 [201, {"request_id"=>"b425bce0-307d-012f-3e68-042b2b8686e6", "Content-Type"=>"application/xml"}, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<response>\n  <data>\n    <fine_print_line_3>line 3</fine_print_line_3>\n    <available_start_date>2012-02-02T06:00:00+05:30</available_start_date>\n    <status>inactive</status>\n    <highlight_line_2>gfgf</highlight_line_2>\n    <original_price>50.00</original_price>\n    <category_id>bc210bb0-52b7-012e-8896-12313b077c61</category_id>\n    <available_end_date>2012-03-25T00:00:00+05:30</available_end_date>\n    <expiry_date>2012-08-25T00:00:00+05:30</expiry_date>\n    <highlight_line_3></highlight_line_3>\n   <product_service>food</product_service>\n   <created_at>2012-02-03T15:43:56+05:30</created_at>\n   <detailed_description>&lt;b&gt;this is the testing detailed&lt;/b&gt; </detailed_description>...
```

I would surely like to post some extra code if required.

Comment: I looked around for majority of suggested ans but could not fine working for me :(

Answer (score 0):

So your data is in XML and you would like to know the content of these fields?

Use Nokogiri:

```
xml = data.send(format_type_method, options_hash)
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
start_date = doc.xpath("//available_start_date").content

p start_date #=> "2012-02-02T06:00:00+05:30"
```

Once you have your fields in variables you can whatever you want.